# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Chrome for refocusing the cursor to within the console?

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to Chrome Developer Tools and am doing a Udemy course on JavaScript. I have a split screen with my course video in a window on the left and a blank Chrome tab on the right with the console open. Often in the course of typing commands the focus will leave the console and move elsewhere and I will have to take my fingers away from the keyboard and use the trackpad to re-select the console pane, enabling me to type again. I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to focuses the cursor in the console, similar to CTRL+L (Win) for focusing the cursor in the address bar. Does such a shortcut exist?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

From within Chrome, you can focus the DevTools console using the shortcut <kbd>Control+`</kbd> (control and backtick).

Google has documentation listing all available keyboard shortcuts for the Chrome DevTools here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Comment: Thank you Trent, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Please consider marking this as the Accepted Answer if it fulfilled your question.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>F6</kbd> will cycle the keyboard focus through various UI elements (URL bar, page display, Dev tools, etc.).  Once in the Dev tools pane, either of these should get you on your way:

- Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (perhaps multiple times in row).  This will close sections, then toggle the secondary Dev tools pane.
- Another option is to check the option **Enable Ctrl + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels** option in the Dev Tools preferences (accessed via 3 vertical dots icon in upper right).